# Unable to start an activity on button click

Tags: java, android

I have a button on main activity which onclick is supposed to start a activity

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void onButtonClick(View v){

    if(v.getId()==R.id.lbutton)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Display.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

lbutton is the id of button

Display.java

```
public class Display extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondsc);
}
}
```

secondsc.xml is a layout file which contains content for the new activity

Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Display">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.lbutton).setOnClickLIstener(new OnClickLIstener(){ void onClick(View v) { onButtonClick(v);}});`

Comment: As I can see you did not `setOnClickListener(this)` and did not make the activity implement `View.OnClickListener` - did you set the `android:onClick="onButtonClick"` attribute in the xml?

Answer (score 3):

remove intent-filter to DisplayActivity in your manifest file:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

And register your clickListener button

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.lbutton).setOnClickLIstener(new OnClickLIstener (){
            void onClick (View v) {
                onButtonClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the button. You can either implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface and implement the `onClick` method (good if you have multiple buttons that need listeners), or use an anonymous class:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    onClick (View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the **`OnButtonClick`** is being executed? I recommend doing it this way:

```
Button lButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lButton);
lButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Display.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**-Daniel**